# Send user to a new view controller after Facebook login

Tags: xcode, viewcontroller

I'm pretty new at coding so this might be really simple but any help would be amazing..

I've added a login screen when you first open the app and integrated the FBSDK.

Once you've logged into Facebook you get taken back to the same `ViewController` that you clicked to login to Facebook.

How would I be able to auto redirect them to a new view controller i've setup once they have received the `FBSDKAccessToken` ? Therefore skip this view controller on startup if they're already logged in?

I'm guessing it would be at `if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])` but I'm unsure of the next part and I can't seem to find any reference to this anywhere with the new `FSBSDK 4.+`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `segue` to present new `ViewController` to the user. Add a `new ViewController` to your storyboard. Control drag from your FBLogin button to the new ViewController and select `Present Modally`. Now select the segue and from the right-upper corner in Xcode select attribute inspector and give some name to the identifier for example loginSuccess. Add this line to your code `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSuccess" sender:self];`
Let me know if you have any difficulty, Here is the full code example for your understanding.

```
- (IBAction)btnFacebookPressed:(id)sender {
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Process error
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
        // Handle cancellations
    } else {
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
        {
            // Do work
            if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
            {

                [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, first_name, last_name, email"}]

                 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
                 {

                     if (!error)
                     {
                         NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;

                       }
                 }];
            }

                    {
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSuccess" sender:self];
                    }
            }
      }
}];

}
@end
```